# Setting CSS li counter value through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the rectangle OL style from http://red-team-design.com/css3-ordered-list-styles/ and it works perfectly, except on one page I've got.

I'm trying to use the style on a paginated search result page, and I don't know how to get the counter value to update correctly:

On the first page of 10 results, the li's are numbered correctly (1, 2, ... 9, 10).

But on page two onwards, the li's are reset and show 1, 2, ...9, 10 again when they should be 11, 12, ...19, 20 etc

Is there any way to specify what the starting count should be on a page, via javascript? The pages are built via XQuery and there is a variable on each page indicating what the start number should be.

Comment: The HTML/CSS for the OL style is on the link, and my search results is just simply a loop of <li>'s in an <ol class="rectangle-list">

Comment: @JordanWall yes, but you have "pages" which nobody sees here; as I understand the problem comes exactly when you switch the magic page. At least give a sample of the page and how can they be connected to each other; e.g. is there any way to know on the second page that it is actually second?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the post - there is a variable on each page with what the start number should be

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The guys from [your example](http://red-team-design.com/css3-ordered-list-styles/) use the following properties:

```
content: counter(li);
counter-increment: li;
```

I assume you can use the [counter-reset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-reset) CSS property to set up the first value of your counters. See [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/counter-reset/) for more examples.

All you need to do is set up this value on a body (according to the examples) when you generate the page, no JavaScript is needed.

Comment: how is this an accepted answer? it doesn't work at all.